# FancyBox Disable Fade Effect

Tags: fancybox

The image zoom effect on [FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) works great. However, for this particular case, I need to disable the fade effect that happens along the zoom effect.

Is it possible to disable the fade effect, while leaving the zoom animation
active?

Help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance, Mariano

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer by using these methods:

```
openOpacity : false,
closeOpacity : false,
```